# Example of a function $f$ which is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$, but max{$f,0$} is NOT Lebesgue integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, examples-counterexamples

Can anyone come up with an example of a function $f$ which is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$, but max{$f,0$} is NOT Lebesgue integrable? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

By definition $f$ is Lebesgue integrable if and only if the functions $f_+ =\max\{ f ,0\}$ and $f_- =\max\{-f ,0\}$ are integrable.

Comment: Does that mean that there is NO function that satisfies the conditions that I mentioned in my question? Please let me know

Comment: Yes it means that there is NO function that satisfies the conditions